# SQL filtered index not working in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Hopefully a very quick question: I'm having some trouble getting the following 
index creation statement to work. I'm using MySQL Workbench.

```
CREATE INDEX HIRE_DATE_INDEX 
ON Employee (hiredate)
WHERE hiredate > '2001-01-01';
```

I'm trying to get the following index creation to work, however regardless of what I look up online the following is listed as the proper syntax but for some reason that is unfathomable at this point, the index is specifically saying that the where clause is in the incorrect place.

I'm clearly missing something in the examples.

(Context, just trying to create a filtered index only interested in dates greater then).

It looks like this should be easy as hell, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the WHERE clause. But MySQL doesn't support filtered index. (Reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html))

```
CREATE INDEX HIRE_DATE_INDEX 
ON Employee (hiredate);
```

Also that command doesn't work if you try to create a primary key. If that's the case, you need to use `ALTER TABLE` command.

Comment: I thought indexes basically created keys that were held for sorting?

Comment: And that's right. But what you are trying to achieve it is not possible in MySQL.

Comment: Right, I'll have to find some sort of work arround then because I can't alter the table unfortunately. Thank you for answering my question, I thought it was the case T_T.